# How to backup Linux directories for non-root users

Tags: linux, backup

I am new to the world of Linux and as part of my learning I would like to understand if it is possible for non-root users to have the ability to run their own backup applications apart from an over-arching backup of the server. If it is possible, what applications (GUI and command line) exist that will allow non-root users to backup their data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure - why wouldn't they be able to? Of course it goes without saying that they'd only be able to back up files that they have at least read access to, and that they'll need write access to wherever they're storing the backup files.

I'm not sure about GUI tools, but `tar -czf file.tar.gz /path/to/files` via cron is usually what I see being done, or possibly using rsnapshot or one of its variants.

Comment: @ErikA - Thanks. Now when you say they would be able to backup files they have read access to, does it mean they could potentially make a backup to all the configuration files in say the /etc folder which I believe has read access? Now I assume if a user plugs in a flashdrive or external harddrive, they would be granted write permissions for the device. Is that assumption correct?

Comment: Yes, he would be able to back up *any* files he has read access to. Whether or not the user would be able to write to a flash drive is dependent on how the system is set up, but I'm guessing that in Ubuntu, users do have the permissions to mount and write to removable USB media.

Comment: @ErikA - Isn't that a danger that the user would be able to backup any files that he/she has read access to? Am unsure what the nature of the danger if any seeing that they will have access to configuration information, et cetera (as not to confuse with etc)

Comment: Typically config files that have sensitive info in them are not world-readable. Apache SSL cert private keys, for instance, or /etc/shadow as well. If you're worried about users looking at how you have daemon X configured, you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: Also - backing up a file is really no different than *reading* a file. There's no way to separate the two.

Comment: @ErikA - Thanks. I am unsure what permissions are assigned by default to say Apache and the directories and files it needs access to or what should I harden so want to make sure I understand what users have access to. I take it that anything installed by root is generally off-limits to the rest of the users i.e. they don't have read or write access.

Comment: @PeanutsMoney, no, that is not a valid assumption. You need to look at the permissions of each file/directory.